# UIDatePicker not responding on first touch

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uidatepicker

I have a Count Down Timer UIDatePicker in storyboard. I've hooked it up to my main ViewController.swift file with an `@IBAction func`, and it listens for the value changed event. The function doesn't get called the first time I change the UIDatePicker, but it gets called on subsequent value changes.

How can I get it to change on the first value change?

Code attached:

```
var timeRemaining: TimeInterval = 0.0

@IBOutlet weak var testTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeRemainingLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func focusTimeSelected(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    timeRemaining = focusTimeDatePicker.countDownDuration
    testTimeLabel.text = String(timeRemaining)
    timeRemainingLabel.text = String(timeRemaining)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
timeRemaining = focusTimeDatePicker.countDownDuration
```

To

```
timeRemaining = sender.countDownDuration
```